# Testing ideas for video recording feature

Tags: manual-testing, ios

We recently implemented a video recording feature to our application.
Its specs are:

- Video should be available to all iOS users
- Video should be available on both iPad and iPhone
- A user can record and playback on iOS devices
- Should support all iOS versions
- Have to be able to support iOS 12

I have come up with a list of test cases, but want to get more ideas from you guys.

Comment: Your question mentions device support specs, but not feature specs. How is the recording mechanism supposed to work? Is there a saving/renaming/deleting function? Does it display the videos, or are they only saved to the camera roll? I recommend rewording your question to focus only on devices, or else reword it with more detail about the actual features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test cases that are based on its specs:

*Video should be available to all iOS users*; this spec is not very clear.

- Does your application have some kind of account sharing feature?
- Or it simply means as long as a user has got an iOS device, this video feature is available to them?
- **Test case**, since it is not really practical to test on every iOS device, I would personally choose a few representative devices; I stole this chart from www.statista.com and www.iossupportmatrix.com [image: iOS iPhone support] [image: iOS support of iPhone and iPad]You may need to choose one or more iPhones to make sure your video feature is working for ***all*** iOS users. I doubt you need to test them all, but the more devices you test, the more confident you are.

*Video should be available on both iPad and iPhone*, this spec is not very clear.

- What do you mean by *available*? Is this video recording feature available or the recorded video that is available?
- **Test case**, you can also refer to the two charts above. Again, I doubt you will need to test all versions of iPhone and iPad.

*A user can record and playback on iOS devices*,

- **Test case**, you may need to test against the boundary values of how long a video is allowed to be.
- **Test case**, you may need to test against how record and playback can handle interrupt and resume
- **Test case**, you may need to playback a video recorded from one iOS device on a different iOS device, testing on different iOS versions too?

Should support all iOS versions,

- You cannot test all of it, choose a few representative ones.

Have to be able to support iOS 12

- As of 16th of August 2018, iOS 12 has not been officially released, you will need to sign up for a beta testing account in order to download it. Check it out here, https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/

Answer (score 1):

There can be numerous test ideas that can be used for video recording feature. Below are some of them:

1. Verify that Recording button should appear to record in video recording mode.
2. Verify that Timer should appear while recording a video.
3. Verify that there should be enough space in the device or SD card to record and save a video.
4. Verify the Play the recording feature and check whether the video have been recorded successfully or not with desired quality.
5. Verify the Recording button, Stop button, Continue button, Cancel button should appear while recording.
6. Verify the Play and Pause feature while play the recorded video.
7. Verify the effect in Recording a Video in Less light.
8. Verify the effect in Recording a Video in Normal light.
9. Verify the effect in Recording a Video in More light.
10. When clicked on recording button, recording time should be display correct.

There are the some of the scenarios that are part of [mobile app testing services.](https://www.qasource.com/mobile-qa)